# I'm having a heard time with selecting an option from the data in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working with Express.js, MongoDB and Mongoose, EJS and I'm having a heard time with selecting an option from the data in the database.

```
<div class="mb-3 col-md-3">
    <label
        for="stage"
        class="form-label text-muted"
        >Stage</label
    >
    <select
        class="form-select"
        name="deal[stage]"
        aria-label="Default select example">
        <option selected>Choose One</option>
        <option value="lead">Lead</option>
        <option value="inquiry">Inquiry</option>
        <option value="qualified">Qualified</option>
        <option value="demo">Demo</option>
        <option value="negotiation">Negotiation</option>
        <option value="closure">Closure</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I can do something like this using ejs and that is fine with a few options, but I'm sure that there is a better way.

```
<div class="mb-3 col-md-3">
    <label
        for="hot"
        class="form-label text-muted"
        >Hot</label
    >
    <select
        id="hot"
        class="form-select"
        value="<% deal.hot %>"
        aria-label="Default select example">
        <option selected>Choose One</option>
        <% if(deal.hot === 'true') { %>
        <option
            value="true"
            selected>
            True
        </option>
        <option value="false">False</option>
        <% } else { %>
        <option value="true">True</option>
        <option
            value="false"
            selected>
            False
        </option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I can get it working using an if/else statement with ejs, and that's fine for fields that have two or three options, but I'm sure there is a better way, and that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This works if anyone else is having the same issue.

```
<div class="mb-3 col-md-3">
  <label for="stage" class="form-label text-muted">Stage</label>
  <select class="form-select" name="deal[stage]">
    <option value="Choose One" <% if (deal.stage === "Choose One"){ %> selected <% } %>>Choose One</option>
    <option value="lead" <% if (deal.stage ==="lead"){ %> selected <% } %>>Lead</option>
    <option value="inquiry" <% if (deal.stage === "inquiry"){ %> selected <% } %>>Inquiry</option>
    <option value="qualified" <% if (deal.stage === "qualified"){ %> selected <% } %>>Qualified</option>
    <option value="demo" <% if (deal.stage === "demo"){ %> selected <% } %>>Demo</option>
    <option value="negotiation" <% if (deal.stage ==="negotiation"){ %> selected <% } %>>Negotiation</option>
    <option value="closure" <% if (deal.stage ==="closure"){ %> selected <% } %>>Closure</option>
  </select>
</div>
```